# Getting records in between two records using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list of objects and need to get the list of records from this list. like I have of Countries and I need to get the list of countries which are in between country with name "Australia" and country "Indonasia", the list will not be sorted.

Am using c#.

I tried to use something like, get the index of first and  second and then use that to get the list with a for loop, but would be handy if it can be done in single query.

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do the following:

```
var elementsBetween = allElements
        .SkipWhile(c => c.Name != "Australia")
        .Skip(1) // otherwise we'd get Australia too
        .TakeWhile(c => c.Name != "Indonasia");
```

you'll get the result you want without iterating through the list 3 times.

(This is assuming your countries are e.g. `Country` items with a `Name` string property.)

Note that this doesn't sort the countries at all - it's unclear from your question whether you want this or not but it's trivial to add an `OrderBy` before the `SkipWhile`.

Comment: You wouldn't need to go through the list 3 times, even without linq. What kind of loops do you usually write?

Comment: Usually when people use indices or counts with LINQ they end up iterating through the list to find said indices or counts. (The OP specifically posted about finding the indices of the two items.) I'd say "especially without LINQ" rather than "even without LINQ" - LINQ makes it a lot easier to accidentally iterate through something.

Comment: I would tend to agree with that. However, part of your answer that lit me up was when you said "without **needing** to iterate through the list 3 times". You don't **need** to iterate through the list if you do it **correctly** with or without LINQ.

Comment: @casey Fair enough. I'll change that :)

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job

```
var query = data.SkipWhile(x => x != "Australia").TakeWhile(x => x != "Indonesia")
```